# QEMU USB passthrough is not working

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I stuck at getting USB passthrough working with Windows 8.1 guest OS on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I started by installing qemu using the Ubuntu Documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM). 
The USB device (Datev mIdentity) was recognized by the guest but I could not get any access. It's the same bug as reported earlier (https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1033727)

lsusb output on host:

```
# lssub
[239775.341958] usb 3-4: hub failed to enable device, error -22
[239775.508845] usb 3-4: reset full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[239775.508893] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Setup ERROR: setup context command for slot 10.
[239775.509931] usb 3-4: hub failed to enable device, error -22
[239775.676980] usb 3-4: reset full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[239775.695110] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800cee83100
[239775.695114] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800cee83148
[239775.695115] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800cee83190
[239775.695517] usb 3-4: usbfs: process 23897 (pcscd) did not claim interface 0 before use
[239786.195869] usb 3-4: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usbfs while 'qemu-system-x86' sets config #1
```

In /var/log/libvirt/qemu/VM.log I found following line:

```
libusb_set_configuration: -6 [BUSY]
```

After a lot of reading,  I set up a udev rule to grant access to the libvirt-group, defined the device in the vm's xml definition and checked if appamor is blocking. Everything looks good, but still the same error.

Then I build qemu from source with --enable-libusb flag set. Still the same error.

QEMU version:

```
# /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -version
QEMU emulator version 2.0.0 (Debian 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.13), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

libsub version:

```
# dpkg -l | grep libusb
ii  libgusb2:amd64                      0.1.6-5                               amd64        GLib wrapper around libusb1
ii  libusb-0.1-4:amd64                  2:0.1.12-23.3ubuntu1                  amd64        userspace USB programming library
ii  libusb-1.0-0:amd64                  2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2                     amd64        userspace USB programming library
ii  libusb-dev                          2:0.1.12-23.3ubuntu1                  amd64        userspace USB programming library development files
ii  libusbredirparser1:amd64            0.6-2ubuntu1                          amd64        Parser for the usbredir protocol (runtime)
```

libvirt version:

```
# dpkg -l | grep libvirt
ii  libvirt-bin                         1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.10                  amd64        programs for the libvirt library
ii  libvirt0                            1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.10                  amd64        library for interfacing with different virtualization systems
ii  python-libvirt                      1.2.2-0ubuntu2                        amd64        libvirt Python bindings
```

At this point I've got no idea what's going on. I appreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're using Ubuntu? Try using another distribution; they have a pretty poor track record. All my KVM hypervisors are now Fedora.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04, but I can't switch to Fedora due to services in use...

Answer (score 1):

`[239786.195869] usb 3-4: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usbfs while 'qemu-system-x86' sets config #1`

There is a conflict between the usbfs driver and qemu-system-x86. You need to follow the following steps to resolve this issue:

`echo "blacklist usbfs" > /etc/modprobe.d/usbfs-conflict.conf`

Update initramfs in order to avoid module to be loaded bootup time. it will update configuration files used in booting process before the root filesystem mounted.

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

restart QEMU and try again.

Comment: Your answer sounds plausible. Unfortunately, I don't have the hardware anymore so I can't test your solution. Thanks anyway!